# Insert a negative value with minus sign at end

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

I want to insert a value into an sql server 2008 table.

The value are like `20.00-` , `10.00-`

The minus sign is at the end of the value.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the table structure you are trying to insert the data in?

Comment: create table t1(c1 numeric(10,5))

Comment: Why can't just change the format that the values are supplied to a normal numeric format? Why should SQL-Server handle this insane format?

Comment: file is coming from SAP.they said they can't change it

Comment: Incoming as a string? Convert it it to `-N` in the client layer. Or insert as `-20.00-0` for giggles.

Comment: **somewhere** between a file coming out of SAP and the data getting inserted into SQL Server, there must be an opportunity to change this around. You should just store *data* in the database, in the most appropriate data type available.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this?

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(-456.00 AS VARCHAR(10)),'-','') + '-'
```

Where 456.00 is your value

Comment: i cant use this in  my insert.but i can first insert the 10.00- as varchar and then can i change it -10.00

Answer (score 0):

You could insert raw data into a staging table first. Then you could either convert the values in the staging table and insert them afterwards into the actual table, or insert and convert at the same time.

Here's how you could go about the conversion.

For every input value, you would need to check if it has a minus. If it does, then one character should be deleted at the last position and one character should be inserted at the first position. Otherwise nothing should be deleted or inserted.

So, essentially you can have an indication in the form of 1 or 0 and use that number to determine how many characters to insert or delete.

There are various methods of obtaining that 1/0 result.

For instance, you could take the input value's last character as a substring and use CHARINDEX to search for `-` within that substring:

```
CHARINDEX('-', LEFT(InputValue, LEN(InputValue)))
```

If the last character of `InputValue` *is* `'-'`, the `CHARINDEX` will return 1, otherwise it will return 0.

Another method, also using `CHARINDEX`, would be to go like this:

```
CAST(CHARINDEX('-', InputValue) AS bit)
```

If `InputValue` has a minus, `CHARINDEX` will return a positive result and `CAST` will convert it to 1. If there is no minus, `CHARINDEX` will give you a 0, which will stay 0 after the cast.

Now you can use the expression's result to determine:

- whether to delete the last character or not:

  ```
  STUFF(InputValue, LEN(InputValue), CAST(CHARINDEX('-', InputValue) AS bit), '')
  ```

  and
- whether to prefix the value with a `'-'`:

  ```
  REPLICATE('-', CAST(CHARINDEX('-', InputValue) AS bit))
  ```

That is, the complete expression is this:

```
REPLICATE('-', CAST(CHARINDEX('-', InputValue) AS bit)) +
STUFF(InputValue, LEN(InputValue), CAST(CHARINDEX('-', InputValue) AS bit), '')
```

In the final statement you could also use `CROSS APPLY` to avoid repetition of the emphasised sub-expression, something aloong the lines of this (assuming you will choose to do insertion + processing):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (columns)
SELECT
  ...
  REPLICATE('-', x.HasMinus) + STUFF(InputValue, LEN(InputValue), x.HasMinus, ''),
  ...
FROM dbo.StagingTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(CHARINDEX('-', InputValue) AS bit)) AS x (HasMinus)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is long but :

```
select IIF(ISNUMERIC(IIF(RIGHT(RTRIM('20.55-'), 1) = '-', '-' + REPLACE('20.55-', '-',''), '20.55-')) = 1, CONVERT(decimal(7,3), IIF(RIGHT(RTRIM('20.55-'), 1) = '-', '-' + REPLACE('20.55-', '-',''), '20.55-')), NULL)
```

Comment: you need to convert the in  varchar

Answer (score -1):

Simply :

```
Select CASE WHEN LEFT(InputValue,1) = '-' THEN '-' ELSE '' END + REPLACE(InputValue,'-','')
```

You may need to Cast it as money (or numeric or decimal)

Comment: just downvoted your answer because try this `Select CASE WHEN LEFT(InputValue,1) = '-' THEN '-' ELSE '' END + REPLACE(InputValue,'-','') `